# Open() function while deploying streamlit app

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, streamlit, deploying

I get an error of no such file or directory while am deploying a streamlit app to streamlit cloud share, what could be the problem, i have all files in the same directory and as a standalone the app works perfectly the error comes only when am deploying the app, i need help

Loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filepath here/savfile)

Answer (score 0):

The files in a Streamlit app are stored in a folder called `app` – as a result, you'll usually need to adjust the file paths when you're deploying an app that you were previously running locally. I'd recommend doing `os.getcwd()` to return the file path and confirm that your file paths are correct.